# R splitting string on predefined location

Tags: r, regex, string, split

I have string, which should be split into parts from "random" locations. Split occurs always from next comma after colon.

My idea was to find colons with

```
stringr::str_locate_all(test, ":") %>% 
  unlist()
```

then find commas

```
stringr::str_locate_all(test, ",") %>% 
  unlist()
```

and from there to figure out position where it should be split up, but could not find suitable way to do it. Feels like there is always 6 characters after colon before the comma, but I can't be sure about that for whole data.

Here is example string:

```
dput(test)
"AA,KK,QQ,JJ,TT,99,88:0.5083,66,55:0.8303,AK,AQ,AJs,AJo:0.9037,ATs:0.0024,ATo:0.5678"
```

Here is what result should be

```
dput(result)
c("AA,KK,QQ,JJ,TT,99,88:0.5083", "66,55:0.8303", "AK,AQ,AJs,AJo:0.9037", 
"ATs:0.0024", "ATo:0.5678")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one option with `strsplit` - replace the `,` after the digit followed by the `.` and one or more digits (`\\d+`) with a new delimiter using `gsub` and then split with `strsplit` in `base R`

```
result1 <- strsplit(gsub("([0-9]\\.[0-9]+),", "\\1;", test), ";")[[1]]
```

-checking

```
> identical(result, result1)
[1] TRUE
```

---

If the number of characters are fixed, use a regex lookaround

```
result1 <-  strsplit(test, "(?<=:.{6}),", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
```

Comment: the first one seems very unsafe and does not depend on colons at all

Comment: As the OP mentioned, the second one can also fail if there are cases that doesn't fit.  So, any regex pattern have the same kind of issue

Comment: um no not really, `Split occurs always from next comma after colon` is pretty easy to code

Comment: @rawr you are right.  I keep the solution as the second one does the exact pattern as OP mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Perehaps we can use `regmatches` like below

```
> regmatches(test, gregexpr("(\\w+,?)+:[0-9.]+", test))[[1]]
[1] "AA,KK,QQ,JJ,TT,99,88:0.5083" "66,55:0.8303"
[3] "AK,AQ,AJs,AJo:0.9037"        "ATs:0.0024"
[5] "ATo:0.5678"
```